# Determine if a related element is above or below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i'm having an unordered list with several elements and i'm using jquery sortable for moving items around - here's my markup:

```
<ul>
    <li id=1>item 1</li>
    <li id=2>item 2</li>
    <li id=3>item 3</li>
    <li rel=2>insert</li>
    <li id=4>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

the "insert" element is related to the LI having ID 2 - my question:
what's the best practice for determing if the related item is above or below the "insert" element? (in this case: above)

Comment: I preusme you mean the jquery ui sortable? Core jquery does not have a sortable

Comment: Assuming the list is vertical you could compare the element indexes (lower means higher up) alternatively you can compare the ordinal positions using `offset().top`. Alternatively you could use `nextAll()` and `prevAll()`, but they involve looping through all the siblings

Comment: Basically [`$().prev()` and `$().next()`](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Comment: jQuery's sortable feature has a .toArray() method that will track item indexes as they are moved, inserted and removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).prevAll("[id=2]").length > 0)
{
//element is above
}


if($(this).nextAll("[id=2]").length > 0)
{
//element is below
}
```

You can use `nextAll` and `prevAll` functions of jquery for this. Here $(this) refers to `insert` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`index` function](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the place of the element and compare it to other elements:

```js
inserted = $('li[rel=2]');

$('ul li').click(function() {
  if (inserted.index() > $(this).index()) {
    console.log('Clicked element is above');
  } else if (inserted.index() < $(this).index()) {
    console.log('Clicked element is below');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id=1>item 1</li>
    <li id=2>item 2</li>
    <li id=3>item 3</li>
    <li rel=2>insert</li>
    <li id=4>item 4</li>
</ul>
```